# Extracting specific data from a pdf into excel

Tags: excel, pdf, extract

community

I need to extract select data from a pdf form into excel. Eventually, the data gathered will be used in another step (excel table) as part of an additional calculation.
I am hoping to find a way to automate this process so I tried importing the pdf file to excel using Power Query. Unfortunately, each time I loaded the pdf, I get a message (Page is blank).
After doing some initial search, I found out that this may be due to the fact the way the pdf file was built originally (not as a table converted to a pdf).
I went back and converted the pdf file into a spreadsheet and now I can actually see the data that I need to extract in excel but needs a lot of cell formatting and rearranging.

I would really like to know if there is an alternative to solving this problem. More importantly, I'd very much appreciate any bright ideas or recommendations on how to best tackle this task since I have to repeat the same process 30+ times.
Also, I don't have a lot of coding experience, knowledge- very minimal.

Thank you so much

Comment: Extracting anything from a PDF is a pain, at some point, there is no way around it, you have to put in the time and effort to clean things up manually. Best option is to try and get original source files from whoever provided the PDFs

Comment: Thank you, sir.